# Change height on datepicker programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In my app I need a different height on a date picker for different devices. When the view controller loads I need to check what is the current device (which I know how to check) and accordingly set the date picker's height which is a problem to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a height constraint to your `datePicker` and change it depending when you need to change the height. So you:

1. Add the height constraint to your `datePicker`
2. Add an Outlet for your constraint `@IBOutlet weak var datePickerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` in your view controller
3. Change it by doing this: `datePickerHeightConstraint.constant = 350` for example

Comment: Wow I never knew that you can actually make outlets from constraints, this works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: And by using proper constraints you should not need any code that determines what device is being used.